# Analytics Builder - Differenciate views between 2 different landing pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, analytics

I currently have 2 different Landing pages live, created with Web Pages in Marketing Cloud. Both landing pages have the same tracking code so I can track views and referring sites in Analytics Builder. 
The tracking seems to be working but Analytics Builder show me a result of all views and referring sites together (123 coming from Instagram in this case) so I cant's differenciate how many of those 123 are from LandingPage1 and how many form LandingPage2)

Both Landing Pages have the same domain but different paths:
Landingpage1: www.mydomain.com/landingpage1
landingpage2: www.mydomain.com/landingpage2

(attached screenshot for more reference)

Is it possible to differenciate both landing pages in analytics builder or since they are within the same domain it is not?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: WAMA is very limited in functionality there is not a way to accomplish this.

You can drill deeper in to each tile by the clicking on the arrows in the lower right hand corner.

I would recommend using another tool such as Google analytics

Comment: Thanks for your input @EazyE!